# How do I clear form fields using knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js

After saving the data from a form I want to clear the fields. I am using knockout js for binding the form fields to the model. What is the best approach for clearing the form fields?

Answer (score 3):

```
function BookViewModel(title, author, pages) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.author = ko.observable(author);
    self.pages = ko.observable(pages);

    self.reset = function() {
        self.title(null);
        self.author(null);
        self.pages(null);
    }
}
var viewModel = new BookViewModel("Windows Presentation Foundation 4.5 - Einführung und Praxis", "Norbert Eder", 400);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgcsayrj/1/)

You could also check the [mapping.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin. Maybe it will help you accomplish it more easily.

Comment: Then you have to do it manually. Check the fiddle I have created for you in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way using a sub model in an observable and then the clear will just change the value to a new object:

Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.formModel = ko.observable(new FormModel());

    self.clear = function () {
        self.formModel(new FormModel());
    }
};

var FormModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable();
    self.surname = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Html:

```
<form data-bind="with: formModel">
    First Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName"/>
    Surame: <input type="text" data-bind="value: surname"/>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.clear">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qb5k9bbn/

Comment: Bear in mind that `with` binding recreates the DOM fragment that it controls upon any `formModel` value change. In case you use some custom UI logic (under that replaced DOM) that needs JS initialization, you might want to re-initialize that UI logic when `formModel` changes